# How to apply ordianal regression in H2O python?

Tags: python-3.x, classification, h2o

I have a target consisting of 5 classes where there is an ordinal relation. I want to implement an ordinal regression for this multi-class classification problem. Here what I tried:

```
train['target'] = train['target'].asfactor()
valid['target'] = valid['target'].asfactor()
test['target'] = test['target'].asfactor()

from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator

hyper_params_glm = {'alpha': [0.001, 0.003, 0.005, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95],
                   'missing_values_handling': ["skip", "mean_imputation"]}

ip_grid_glm = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(                 
                    standardize = True,
                    family='ordinal', keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, 
                    fold_assignment = "Modulo",lambda_search = True,
                    intercept = True,seed=2345, early_stopping = True, nfolds = 5)
                    ,hyper_params=hyper_params_glm)

ip_grid_glm.train(x=finalFeatures, y='AnsQ1', training_frame=train)
```

However I got the error:

> Argument `family` should be a ?Enum["multinomial", "quasibinomial",
>   "poisson", "gamma", "gaussian", "tweedie", "binomial"], got string
>   ordinal

I have also changed target type as numeric using `asnumeric()`, however again I got the same error.

How can I apply ordinal regression for my multi-class classification?

**EDIT:** If I understood correctly from the document [link](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html), if I use multinomial family with more than 2 categorical values, then it will take into account the order of the categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of H2O are you using? The "ordinal" option for `family` [looks like](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md#new-feature-14) it was added in 3.18.0.3.

Hopefully http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#logistic-ordinal-regression-ordinal-family answers your other questions? It explains the mathematical differences between "ordinal" and "multinomial".

(But I think the short answer to the question in your edit is "yes", as it says: "[it is for] variables that are discreet, as in classification, but that can be ordered, as in regression.")